# r- Unclear abbreviations of cases' labels on plot

Tags: r, plot, abbreviation

I have a problem with display of abbreviated cases' names on the following plot.

The code I use:

```
install.packages("HSAUR2")
library(HSAUR2)
data("Forbes2000", package="HSAUR2")
head(Forbes2000)
attach(Forbes2000)
not_na<-subset(Forbes2000,complete.cases(Forbes2000)
order_profits<-(order(not_na$profits))    
top50<-not_na[order_profits[1946:1995], c("name","sales","profits", "assets")]    
plot(top50$sales~top50$assets,col= "blue", pch = 19, cex = 1, lty = "solid", lwd = 1)
top50$assets,top50$sales,  abbreviate(name,1, strict="TRUE",named="FALSE"), cex= .7,pos=4)
```

[image: plot with abbreviated labels]
I tried to make it differently:

```
plot(top50$sales~top50$assets,col= "blue", pch = 19, cex = 1, lty = "solid", lwd = 1)
ab<-abbreviate(name,1, strict="TRUE",named="FALSE")
text(top50$assets,top50$sales,  labels=ab, cex= .7,pos=4)
```

But had the same result.

If I use full labels instead, the display is ok, but plot gets messy:

```
plot(top50$sales~top50$assets,col= "blue", pch = 19, cex = 1, lty = "solid", lwd = 1)
text(top50$assets,top50$sales,  labels=top50$name, cex= .7,pos=4)
```

[image: plot with full names]

Could you show, how to make abbreviations look well? Is there any mistake in my code or the problem is due to soft issues?

Comment: what kind of abbreviations are OK for you? if you want first letter of each word, you can split each characters and paste first letter together.

Comment: from the first image it's seen that abbreviated labels are blurred and unclear, though there's no such a proble using full labels.
i mean, is there any mistake in my code or the problem is due to soft issues?

what u suggest is a solution, of course, thanks for it. but i'd prefer to understand the cause of the problem with my code.

Comment: your text labels are not blurred or unclear. you `name` variable was attached from the full data, which is much longer than the top50 subset you selected. so the x and y positions are recycled for additions labels in `name`. you should use `ab <- abbreviate(top50$name, 1, ...`

Comment: oh, silly mistake
thanks a lot again!